# Adding a product to a variety of grouped products in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a way that in woocommerce a product can be added to a variety of grouped products rather than just one which seems to be the default in the dropdown box. As it is, to add a product to more than one group I would have to duplicate every product I want to do this for which is 180 products!

Cheers

Matt

Comment: Just for future reference I was wondering what exactly was wrong with this question that led to it getting 2 negative responses within 10 minutes of being posted?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [**Product Bundles**](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-bundles/) or [**Chained Products**](http://www.woothemes.com/products/chained-products/).

Answer (score 0):

"Composite" bundles from the Composite Products addon seems to be what would solve the problem, but who wants to spend a $80 on the WooCommerce package that would allow that, when it seems relatively simple to do what Matt is suggesting, where instead of a associating a product with only a single parent group, the entry field could be of a list type, and then that product could easily be added to multiple parent groups?

I am facing the same problem as Matt right now... To buy or not to buy the Composite Products package?  I only have a few products right now that this would be helpful for so I'm inclined not to buy, and will likely create a  variable product instead, where each variable parent includes all the child products as seperate options. This means duplication of entry of each child inside each parent and also complicates inventory tracking of the child products, but for a small business with few products, it makes more sense...

Too bad the WooCommerce free storefront package doesn't offer this as standard, it seems like a basic need in my opinion...

Answer (score -2):

Actually yes woocommerce packages have really high price. I usually for ecommerce work with Magento,  I thought to try this time woocomerce and a lot of troubles for all specific features i need to pay some package for 100$. If you can choose between woocommerce and Magento i will say go with Magento!